# Swift: render transcription with timestamp

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app that transform from speech to text, and now I'm trying to display result on screen, and I'm wondering how to do like this one (from `Otter` app):

[image]

Basic idea:

- 1 conversation has multiple sentences
- each sentence has multiple words, those words have their own timestamps and will be highlighted to match with the current audio playback time
- We can click on each word to play audio at that timestamp
- You can see in the end of the GIF, we can scroll the slider and words will automatically be highlighted

---

My thoughts:

- I'm thinking of rendering `UILabel` (or `UIButton`) that represents for each word, by doing that we can click on each Label and jump to correct time, but I don't know how to append `UILabel` to another `UILabel` in same line, tried searching but can't find a solution. A sentence can be long and contains multiple words because of that it will need to break to multiline if needed
- Also I'm wondering that, to make the labels auto highlight when audio playing (or when scrolling the slider) they should some how "watch" for audio playback time changes (or slider value change). 1 conversation may contains a lot of sentences and if we do "watch" in un-efficient way will cause bad performance

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend to use `UIButton` instead of `UILabel`, because it is easy to setup tap recogniser to it and it support highlight out of box.
If we speak about easy way to put several views one right after another first thought is to use `UIStackView` – it is easy to customise and use.
The most difficult part is track audio playback and synchronise it with UI. First approach is to track playback and when it gets into certain transcription range gets its index and highlight button at same index at `arrangedSubviews` of `UIStackView`.

Comment: seems like `UIStackView` doesn't have auto-line break if the content inside exceed its size, right? is Collection View good for this?

Comment: Yes, you should manage stack view manually. Collection view fits absolutely everywhere, but its more complicated solution. But if you not afraid of this you have nearly unlimited possibilities using custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches and try figure out myself, I see that Otter uses `UITextView` to display each sentence, and their idea inspired me.

I ended up finish it with `UITextView` and Attributed text to get the result same  like them

For watching playback time changes, I use key value observer. Each sentence will observe playback time, and if the time is in the sentence's time boundary, then the sentence will find out which word inside it should be highlighted